# Insert into select, target data unaffected

Tags: sql

We have a simple query

```
INSERT INTO table2
    SELECT * 
    FROM table1
    WHERE condition;
```

I can read somewhere that to use `INSERT INTO SELECT` statement, the following condition must be fulfilled:

- The existing records in the target table are unaffected

What does it mean?

Comment: It means that you INSERT new rows, and the old rows are unchanged. (UPDATE updates old rows.)

Answer (score 0):

INSERT is a SQL operations that add some new rows into your table, with not affect on the others. This is happening instead of UPDATE operations, that cand affect multiple rows from your table if you use a wrong WHERE Clause.

Comment: I meant about a logical wrong WHERE clause :) not a syntax wrong one :)